# how to use entry widget and other tkinter things?

Tags: python, tkinter

The 3 things I'm trying to do are:

• replace the Label widget that displays as "!replace!" in the GUI (and is named placeHolder in the code) with an Entry widget. When the "New Game" button is pressed, the initial number of balls in the new game should be the number in the Entry widget.

• whenever fewer than three balls remain, inactivate the buttons that would result in illegal moves.

• use the status Label (statusLabel in the code) to provide more feedback to the player. Remove the code that prints information to the Python shell, and instead use the status label to display information such as how many balls the computer took, win/lose status ("You win!" or "Computer wins!"), etc.

```
    # Note: if you want to use additional tkinter widgets, you will need to add their names to
    # the import list below
    from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Button, Label, Entry, END, LEFT, RIGHT, SUNKEN
    from time import sleep
    import random

    # To run this code, load into Python, and execute runNim(n), where n is desired initial number
    # of balls, in the Python shell
    #

    # This class is just like the solution to HW 6 Q2 with three small changes related to GUI.
    # See comments starting with # ##.
    class NimGame():

        def __init__(self, numberOfBalls):
            self.numberOfBallsRemaining = numberOfBalls
            print("Nim game initialized with {} balls.".format(self.numberOfBallsRemaining))

        def remainingBalls(self):
            return self.numberOfBallsRemaining

        def take(self, numberOfBalls):
            if (numberOfBalls < 1) or (numberOfBalls > 3) or (numberOfBalls > self.numberOfBallsRemaining):
                print("You can't take that number of balls. Try again.")
                # ## Update statusLabel in the GUI to tell user they can't take that many balls.
                # For the homework, you'll deactivate the buttons that allow such choices,
                # so this whole "if" will no longer be used/necessary.
                statusLabel.configure(text="You can't take that number of balls. Try again.")
            else:
                self.numberOfBallsRemaining = self.numberOfBallsRemaining - numberOfBalls
                print("You took {} balls. {} remain.".format(numberOfBalls, self.numberOfBallsRemaining))
                if self.numberOfBallsRemaining == 0:
                    print("You win!")
                else:
                    # ## After removing player-chosen balls, update graphics and then pause for 1.0 seconds
                    # before removing computer-chosen balls.  This way the player can "see" the
                    # intermediate status.  Perhaps think about a nicer way of showing this.
                    updateGraphics()
                    sleep(1.0)

                    computerMaxBalls = min(3, self.numberOfBallsRemaining)
                    # It is certainly okay to change this code so that the computer plays more intelligently!
                    compBallsTaken = random.randint(1,computerMaxBalls)
                    self.numberOfBallsRemaining = self.numberOfBallsRemaining - compBallsTaken

                    # ## After removing computer-chosen balls, update graphics again.
                    updateGraphics()
                    print("Computer took {} balls. {} remain.".format(compBallsTaken, self.numberOfBallsRemaining))
                    if self.numberOfBallsRemaining == 0:
                        print("Computer wins!")

    # global variables used for placement of balls
    canvasHeight = 200
    canvasWidth = 610
    canvasBorderBuffer = 10
    maxBallSize = 100
    # the values of global variables below are computed and set in initializeNimAndGUI
    # ballSize
    # halfBallSize 
    # spaceBetweenBalls 
    # leftmostBallXPosition
    # ballYPosition

    # 1. clear the canvas
    # 2. draw balls on canvas equal to number remaining in the Nim game
    def updateGraphics():
        canvas.delete('all')   
        centerX = leftmostBallXPosition
        centerY = ballYPosition
        for i in range(nimGame.remainingBalls()):
            canvas.create_oval(centerX - halfBallSize,
                               centerY - halfBallSize,
                               centerX + halfBallSize,
                               centerY + halfBallSize,
                               fill="#9999ff")
            centerX = centerX + spaceBetweenBalls + ballSize
            canvas.update_idletasks()


    # Callback functions invoked by GUI buttons

    def takeBalls(numberToTake):
        nimGame.take(numberToTake)

    def initializeNewGame():
        numberOfBalls = e1.get() # change this to read from Entry widget you add to GUI
        initializeNimAndGUI(numberOfBalls)   

    #####

    # 1. create a NimGame object with specified number of balls
    # 2. clear the graphics canvas
    # 3. based on number of balls, compute values ball size and spacing and set
    #     global variable used for drawing the balls.
    # 
    def initializeNimAndGUI(numberOfBalls):
        global nimGame
        global ballSize, halfBallSize, spaceBetweenBalls, leftmostBallXPosition, ballYPosition

        nimGame = NimGame(numberOfBalls)
        canvas.delete('all') 
        ballSize = min(maxBallSize, int(((canvasWidth-canvasBorderBuffer)//numberOfBalls)/1.2))
        halfBallSize = ballSize // 2
        spaceBetweenBalls = int(0.2 * ballSize)
        leftmostBallXPosition = (canvasBorderBuffer//2) + (spaceBetweenBalls//2) + halfBallSize
        ballYPosition = canvasHeight // 2

        updateGraphics()
        statusLabel.configure(text="Started new game.")


    # create GUI for Nim Game, including
    # 1. canvas where balls will be shown
    # 2. some buttons, to the right of the canvas, for taking balls or starting a new game
    # 3. a label, below the canvas and buttons, for status messages
    #
    def createGUI():
        global rootWindow
        global canvas
        global statusLabel
        global textEntry

        rootWindow = Tk()
        rootWindow.title("Play Nim")
        canvasAndButtons = Frame(rootWindow)
        canvas = Canvas(canvasAndButtons, height=canvasHeight, width=canvasWidth, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=2)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT)

        buttonframe = Frame(canvasAndButtons)
        button1 = Button(buttonframe, text='Take 1', command=lambda:takeBalls(1))
        button2 = Button(buttonframe, text='Take 2', command=lambda:takeBalls(2))
        button3 = Button(buttonframe, text='Take 3', command=lambda:takeBalls(3))
        button4 = Button(buttonframe, text='New Game', command=initializeNewGame)

        # replace this with an Entry widget
        e1 = Entry(rootWindow, bd=1)

        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        button3.pack()
        button4.pack()
        e1.pack(side=RIGHT)
        buttonframe.pack(side=RIGHT)
        canvasAndButtons.pack()
        statusLabel = Label(rootWindow)
        statusLabel.pack()

    # Call 'runNim' with the desired number of initial balls
    #
    def runNim(numberOfBalls):
        createGUI()
        initializeNimAndGUI(numberOfBalls)   
        rootWindow.mainloop()
```

Confused on why I cannot read from the entry widget when playing a new game. I used e1.get(). Help would be greatly appreciated. If you have time for the other 2 things thanks!

Comment: Why can't you read from the entry widget? What happens when you do?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Phirom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Phirom\Documents\Comp. Science\Homework 9\Homework9.py", line 93, in initializeNewGame
    numberOfBalls = e1.get() # change this to read from Entry widget you add to GUI
NameError: name 'e1' is not defined